# Define a ndd for each language in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, routes, internationalization, symfony4

I'm using Symfony v4, and I'd like to do the following thing :

If I arrived from the url http://www.mywebsite.fr => define the locale to fr and only check the route define for fr-fr

If I arrived from the url http://www.mywebsite.en => define the locale to en and only check the route define for en-gb

My road are defined with annotation like this :

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "en-gb":"/home.html",
 *     "fr-fr":"/accueil.html"
 * }, name="home.index")
 */
```

Is it something possible just doing some configuration, or do I have to use a subscriber to check the host and change the locale ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do I understand right, that when someone visits "https://mywebsite.en/" then they should be redirected to "https://mywebsite.en/home.html"?

Comment: No, the idea is : if I go on mywebsite.en/home.html, I go to the function with the route defined on top, with the _locale value en-gb. And if I go on mywebsite.en/accueil.html, I have a 404

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I get it. Maybe you should add a small table to the question with url, path, response, locale. For example like this: fr,accueil,200,fr-fr fr,home,404,fr-fr en,accueil,404,en-gb en,home,200,en-gb

Comment: I would expect this to be the default behavior, but I haven't had the chance to use the internationalized routes yet. Maybe someone else knows how to ensure localized routes are only usable in the matching domain/locale